# How to assign priority to a Thread via the web UI of Microsoft TFS tool

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

One of the available columns while querying for work items of type 'Thread' is the Priority column.
How can I ***assign*** priority to a Thread via the web UI of Microsoft TFS?

See also the screenshot depicting that the Priority column is indeed available but always comes with empty values:

[Screenshot: Querying TFS work items of type 'Thread'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVhPW.png)

Hopefully, this feature is indeed available (since having a list of Threads without some kind of prioritization/categorization is hard to keep track of).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work item type "Thread" isn't in stock TFS; it's coming from a custom process template created by your organization. Talk to your TFS administrator (or the process template owner) to determine proper usage.

In general, as long as you have access to modify work items, you should be able to open a work item and set a value for any field that's not read-only.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still cannot upvote your response since I don't have the proper reputation points.